# Safari select dropdown showing empty fields

Tags: html, css, safari

I have tried the following solutions without luck:For some reason Safari is including extra lines for empty fields in a select box. It's fine in Chrome and Firefox

Here is an example: http://www.ninesixty.co.nz/jazzbags/pullbows/

I have tried the following solutions without luck:

```
select [value=""] {     display: none; }

select:empty {   display:none; }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could accomplish this with CSS because Safari uses an overlay for dropdowns, but you can accomplish this with JavaScript

```
var selectOption = document.querySelectorAll('#slct option');
for (var i = 0; i < selectOption.length; i++) {
  var item = selectOption[i];
  if (item.innerHTML === "") {
    item.remove();
  };
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat. Really appreciate your swift and accurate help GumZ